# Легкий дистрибутив linux

Tags: linux

У меня старый ноутбук lenovo ideapad 110-15acl на винде и работаю с android studio она у меня совсем скрепит. Поможет ли линукс выжить что-то большее и какой дистрибутив поможет

Comment: Скорее всего упираешься в жёсткий диск по производительности на типовых операциях. Поменяй на ssd - минимум проги запускаться будут быстрее. С математикой (архивирование, видео) лучше не станет - тут только новое железо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> lenovo ideapad 110-15acl

Посмотрел в интернете характеристики ноута. Можно конечно попробовать варианты с Linux на основе какой-нибудь лёгкой графической оболочки (LXDE например), но не думаю, что Вы от этого много выиграете (моё ИМХО).

К сожалению, рано или поздно настаёт время, когда нужно задуматься о новом железе.

Answer (score 2):

Под кодерство на старом пк хорошо подойдёт **"Xubuntu"**. Так как по идеи у него почти весь функционал есть от Ubuntu, просто имеет простую оболочку. (не советую использовать Lubuntu, почему то в то время когда я его использовал, он умирал даже и на нормальном компьютере.
Для установки студии вот тебе [инструкция](http://blog.sedicomm.com/2019/02/08/ustanovka-android-studio-3-2-1-na-ubuntu-18-04-i-ubuntu-18-10-ispolzuya-ppa/)...
Если ты не особо любишь дебиан сборки, то посмотри на **enoch** облегчёный дистрибутив **[Pentoo](https://www.pentoo.ch/download/)** (за основу взята генту, просто так же убрано всё ненужное)

Answer (score 2):

Используй Arch linux, так как дистрибутив очень лёгкий.
Во вторых не нужно использовать DE, если ты кодер - то разберёшься с WM - он легче для железа.
Могу посоветовать русскую сборку https://ctlos.github.io/

Comment: Да, Arch Linix хорош для разработки - именно под нее он и заточен

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас на [Celeron-e](https://boo.ua/catalog/dlya-neslozhnykh-zadach/noutbuk-lenovo-ideapad-110-15ibr-80t7004tra/?gclid=CjwKCAiAlO7uBRANEiwA_vXQ-8ED9APK7toTP0Jpa2DlrQemFzLA0YCGuKv-vvD68hFdudJaXUG68RoCqLYQAvD_BwE), то нет. И то что у вас стоит облегчённая версия линухи, это лучший вариант для вас. Я бы вам посоветовал копить на что-то [такое](https://hisystems.com.ua/g37916660-komplekt-yader), но учтите, к такому нужно ещё блокпитания миниму 500Ватт, видеокарту средненькую и жёсткий диск можно достать из ноута. Ну и коробку желательно. Если в игры не гонять, комплект с 16озу, то это примерно: 4400 + 1000(видео) + 700 БП(бу 750Ватт) + 300 (бу коробка) = 6400Грн (~17к руб.).

Есть второй вариант, учить вмесо native (Java, Kotlin), учить кроссплатформенный вариант, например Flutter, собирать будет долго, но HotReload для вас будет счастье, также можно изучить что полегче VS or Intellij

Вспомнил, есть ещё такая штука как [Vim](https://habr.com/ru/post/426255/) или ему подобные вещи. И конечно с компиляцией прийдётся разобраться, но это такой OldSchool что после этого можно потерять любое желание заниматься этим.

**UPD:** как варик, ещё можно рассмотреть вариант с облачным PC (OS), когда-то натыкался на разные варинты, тут уж, вам гугл в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Добить память до восьми гигов (если возможно), поставить какой-нибудь Xubuntu и отказаться от использования IDE вообще (а пользоваться vim и make), причём принципиален именно последний пункт, а первые два опциональны — и полетает ещё годиков пять.